# Wordplay subtraction paradox

Tags: wordplay, pattern

There are words from which you can remove a "chunk", leaving a new word.  Like this:

```
    WISHBONE

   WI SHBO NE

 WI   SHBO   NE 

WI   <poof!>  NE

WI            NE

   WI     NE

     WINE
```

There are also words that work the other way, for which inserting a "chunk" produces a new word.  For example, you can insert the chunk AUTIFI into the word BEER to make BEAUTIFIER.

A "chunk" is a string of consecutive letters.  It must consist of at least two letters (no single-letter chunks).  It does not need to be a valid English word.

Now, what if I told you there are words into which you can insert a chunk, then remove the same consecutive string of letters, and get a **different** word from the original word?

*What the heck am I talking about?!*

I have come up with about 11 examples of this strange phenomenon.

(Too easy?  Too hard?  Try the counterpart [addition paradox](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/wordplay-addition-paradox).)

---

**Afterword:**

Here are my 11 examples:

> Start with BEECHES --> insert ES --> obtain BESEECHES --> remove ES --> obtain BESEECH
>
>   Start with BEING --> insert ING --> obtain BINGEING --> remove ING --> obtain BINGE
>
>   Start with CODER --> insert DE --> obtain DECODER --> remove DE --> obtain DECOR
>
>   Start with CODERS --> insert DE --> obtain DECODERS --> remove DE --> obtain DECORS
>
>   Start with DEDUCT --> insert ED --> obtain DEDUCTED --> remove ED --> obtain DUCTED
>
>   Start with DEFEND --> insert DE --> obtain DEFENDED --> remove DE --> obtain FENDED
>
>   Start with PALED --> insert ED --> obtain PEDALED --> remove ED --> obtain PEDAL
>
>   Start with POSES --> insert SSES --> obtain POSSESSES --> remove SSES --> obtain POSSE
>
>   Start with REDESIGN --> insert ED --> obtain REDESIGNED --> remove ED --> obtain RESIGNED
>
>   Start with PAIRED --> insert RE --> obtain REPAIRED --> remove RE --> obtain REPAID
>
>   Start with DAUNTED --> insert UN --> obtain UNDAUNTED --> remove UN --> obtain UNDATED

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any word in a pattern so that

> you can remove the same chunk from two different places

works as the intermediate word. For example:

> `RESIGNED` → `R(ED)ESIGNED` → `REDESIGN(-ed)`
>  A wordfinder search through Qat is [here](https://quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=ACB%3BABC%3BACBC%3B%7CC%7C%3D2-&ent=Search&dict=0).

Comment: It seems like you don't even need that, since the intermediate step when the chunk is inserted doesn't seem to have to be a word. For example: rot13(ybtvfg|vp| -> ybt|vp|vfg. Nygubhtu ybtvfg vf abg n jbeq, guvf fgvyy nccrnef gb or inyvq.)

Answer (score 2):

> If the word is **[Left][Right]** turned **[Left][Extra chunk][Right]**, this chunk must be removed from somewhere else. Let's say it consists of six parts, as in **[1][2][[Extra chunk 1][Extra chunk 2]][3][4]** (1 or 4 can be empty): 
>  If **[[Extra chunk 1][Extra chunk 2]] = [2][Extra chunk 1]**, it still changes the result as long as **[2] != [Extra chunk 2]**. 
>  If **[[Extra chunk 1][Extra chunk 2]] = [Extra chunk 2][3]**, it still changes the result as long as **[3] != [Extra chunk 1]**.

Answer (score 1):

> Trainer
>  Rain
>  Terrain

Is this the type of thing you're looking for?

Comment: The OP wants a generalized pattern.

Comment: Ah that's a shame. Was fun to come up with that one anyway @Nautilus